# Spring bean throwing error on creation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I am trying to create a bean and I am getting an error thrown.  I have narrowed it down to this specific bean and after referencing the [API documents](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/) , I don't understand why it is getting thrown whenever I deploy my .war file.  Hopefully I am missing something simple.

Here is the app-security.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd

    <beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=mydomain,dc=com" />
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.current.project"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is a snippet of my maven pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <spring.security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

And here is the error thrown:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 88 in XML document from class path resource [app-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 88; columnNumber: 66; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'constructor-arg'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Can you try by use the list of URLs instead of the constructor-arg?  Can't explain why it wouldn't work, but might get you past your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must fully qualify all XML elements:

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=mydomain,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="cn=manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

as `beans` is not a default namespace. Since you never use default Spring Security namespace in your snippet, just make `beans` a default one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

and declare beans as usual.

Comment: I am using Spring Security in the rest of the file, but all of those beans and configs work just fine.  This is the bean I was able to narrow down as the root cause of the error.  Is there any way I can get it to work without changing the namespace?  Or should I just include this in the regular `spring.xml` file?

Comment: @James: my first code snippet should work, without any changes to namespaces. Or alternatively move it to ordinary Spring file and import it, just like you suggested.